# How to write the php code in onchange attribute?

Tags: javascript, php

How to write the php code in onchange event.

**Code:**

```
<select id="country" name="country" onChange=" if(this.value=='other'){ showHint(this.value); this.form['other'].style.visibility='visible'; }else{  showHint(this.value);this.form['other'].style.visibility='hidden';};" class="DropDown" >

  <option value="0">Select Country</option>

   <?php while($sel_rows=mysql_fetch_array($sel_exe)) { ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $sel_rows['CountryId']; ?>"><?php echo $sel_rows['CountryName']; ?></option>

   <?php } ?>

</select>
```

In onChange event I want to fetch country from database instead of static how can I do this?

like.

```
if(this.value=='fetch from the database instead of other')
```

Comment: This is a task for Javascript with AJAX. Look it up!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different function to load data form database like

onChange="load_data()"

inside of this java-script function you can run ajax request and load require data form database

```
   <script>
     function load_data()
     {
        if(this.value=='other'){ 
           showHint(this.value);       
           this.form['other'].style.visibility='visible'; 

          //Jquery ajax request 
          $.ajax({
            //your database call-up script 
            url: "test.php",
            context: document.body,
            success: function(data){
             this.value==data;
           }
         });

        }else{ 
          showHint(this.value);
          this.form['other'].style.visibility='hidden'

        }
     }

  </script>
```

Comment: How to fetch the other from the database instead of static

Comment: I think you need basic idea about Ajax you can learn about Ajax form this link (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp) here success:function(data) that data variable have data-set your test.php return the country data set.. you need to write database query and php fetch to return the data from database this was happen in test.php file